# How to use react-redux with HOC component to wait for data fetching?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

This is my Component and i want to fetch some data from API and then pass it to children but i got error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

As i think i did everything right. in componentWillMount I am fetching info about film with ID=211672 from moviedb API and then setting info about movie in redux store, while movie is undefined, i am displaying simpile  when movie isn't undefined returning component

Pls Elaborate on what i did wrong!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getInfoAboutMovie } from '../../actions/movies.actions';


const AppWrapper = MainComponent =>
class extends Component {
    state = {}

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getInfo(211672);
    }

    render() {
      <div>
        {this.props.movie === 'undefined' ?
          <div> Do something while movie is not fetched </div> :
          <MainComponent {...this.props} />}
      </div>
    );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    if (state.movies.movie !== undefined) {
        return {
            isFetching: state.movies.isFetching,
            movie: state.movies.movie,
        };
    }
    return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getInfo: (movieId) => {
        dispatch(getInfoAboutMovie(movieId));
    },
});

const App = props =>
    <div>{`Users: ${props.movie.id}`}</div>;

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppWrapper(App)));
```

**Main.jsx** Have the following Route

```
<Route exact path="/test" component={AppWrapper} />
```

**movies.actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_KEY } from '../util.const';

export const REQUEST_MOVIES = 'REQUEST_MOVIES';

function requestPopularMovies(loadmore) {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_MOVIES,
        loadmore,
    };
}

export const INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE = 'INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE';

const infoAboutMovie = movie => ({
    type: INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE,
    movie,
});

export const getInfoAboutMovie = movieId => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestPopularMovies());
    return axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(infoAboutMovie(res.data));
        });
};
```

**res.data** I am getting

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/qLmdjn2fv0FV2Mh4NBzMArdA0Uu.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection": null,
  "budget": 74000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 10751,
      "name": "Family"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Animation"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "name": "Comedy"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "http://www.minionsmovie.com/",
  "id": 211672,
  "imdb_id": "tt2293640",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Minions",
  "overview": "Minions Stuart, Kevin and Bob are recruited by Scarlet 
Overkill, 
a super-villain who, alongside her inventor husband Herb, hatches a plot to 
 take over the world.",
  "popularity": 455.619878,
  "poster_path": "/q0R4crx2SehcEEQEkYObktdeFy.jpg",
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "name": "Universal Pictures",
      "id": 33
    },
    {
      "name": "Illumination Entertainment",
      "id": 6704
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
  {
    "iso_3166_1": "US",
    "name": "United States of America"
  }
  ],
  "release_date": "2015-06-17",
  "revenue": 1156730962,
  "runtime": 91,
  "spoken_languages": [
  {
    "iso_639_1": "en",
    "name": "English"
  }
  ],
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": "Before Gru, they had a history of bad bosses",
  "title": "Minions",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 6.4,
}
```

**movies.js** (reducer)

```
import { RECEIVE_MOVIES, REQUEST_MOVIES, INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE, SEARCH_MOVIE } from '../actions/movies.actions';

const initMovies = [{
  path: 'paths',
  backdrop_path: '',
  id: '',
  original_title: '',
  overview: '',
}];

function movies(
  state = {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    data: initMovies,
    howMuchToLoad: 6,
  },
  action,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_MOVIES:
      let howMuchToLoads;
      if (state.howMuchToLoad > 20) {
        howMuchToLoads = 6;
      } else {
        howMuchToLoads = state.howMuchToLoad;
      }
      if (action.loadmore !== undefined) {
        howMuchToLoads = state.howMuchToLoad + 6;
      }
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false,
        howMuchToLoad: howMuchToLoads,
      });
    case RECEIVE_MOVIES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        data: action.movies,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt,
      });
    case INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        movie: action.movie,
      });
    case SEARCH_MOVIE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        query: action.query,
        data: action.movies,
        howMuchToLoad: 200,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default movies;
```

Comment: Can you share your `movies.actions'` code

Comment: added movies.action.js @Aaqib

Comment: What are you getting in res.data? Can we post res.data value?

Comment: @G_S updated check it

Comment: Am I missing it? I am not seeing what res.data you have in your question.

Comment: try to reload !

Comment: Fetching data from componentWillMount is an anti-pattern, that can lead to unexpected behaviour. You can read more about cWM functioning here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671

Comment: @Dez same thing happens with componentDidMount already tried

Comment: Add your reducer, please. Anyway for loading async content you should use cDM.

Comment: @Dez added  movies reducer

Comment: in your INFO_ABOUT_MOVIE, are you getting expected value in action.movie?

Comment: @G_S everything in actions,reducers works right! tested with Redux DevTools

Comment: As @Dez suggested, since it is trying to load async content, can you take a look at redux thunk middleware which returns proper promise after getting content?

Comment: @G_S yes everything works properly

Comment: can you post the changes  that you did after which it started working fine? It could help others facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in your `combineReducers` you are calling your movies reducer as `movies`. So I would make this changes in order to make your code work smooth.

Add this `movie: {}` to your initialState in your reducer and delete `initMovies` because is useless code (is not to blame that you can't make it work, but useless code is useless):

```
function movies(
  state = {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    data: initMovies,
    howMuchToLoad: 6,
    movie: {},
  },
  action,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
```

so in your component you can get rid of the check you were doing in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isFetching: state.movies.isFetching,
        movie: state.movies.movie,
    }; 
};
```

Finally in your component check movie is being sent in `props` to avoid error while async data is not yet fetched, though you should control it with the prop `isFetching` to be clearer and control what to render depending on the fetching state:

```
const App = props => 
    <div>{`Users: ${props.movie ? props.movie.id : ''}`}</div>;
```

I still suggest you to do the action call in componentDidMount for the reasons explained in my comment.

Also another suggestion is to keep actions as simpler as possible. I would take the axios call to the component in cDM and send to the action the response data.

```
// action
export const getInfoAboutMovie = movie => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestPopularMovies());
    dispatch(infoAboutMovie(movie));
};

// component
import { API_KEY } from '../util.const';
...

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/211672?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`)
        .then((res) => {
           this.props.getInfo(res.data);
        // Manage the errors properly
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    }
```

Comment: Ty, the problem gone when i set movie initial value!